# How can i connect to presto pyhive?

Tags: python, python-unicode, pyhive

I want to connect presto using **pyhive** in zeppelin

now, I follows about https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive

I use the connect function and correct parameters.

```
%python
from pyhive import presto
cursor =  presto.connect(host='localhost',
                port=10000,
                username='id:password').cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10')
```

but it does not work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-557261260901431465.py", line 278, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_python-557261260901431465.py", line 266, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyhive/presto.py", line 206, in execute
    self._process_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyhive/presto.py", line 263, in _process_response
    response_json = response.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 650, in json
    return json.loads(self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_32_le.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf32' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-7: code point not in range(0x110000)
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to separate username and password?
`presto.connect(host='xxx', port=xxx, username='xxx', password='xxx')`worked for me.

Comment: i can find a anwser !
i wrong the port .. username ='id:password' is right!~

Comment: The problem here is character encoding - somewhere you have `utf32 little endian` set and it is having a problem decoding the data returned. Try setting this to `utf-8` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

My Connection looks like:

```
presto.connect(host=url, port=port_num, protocol='https', username=user, password=pass)
```

Of note, port is a `str`, not an `int` in my input.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the error is related to decoding response from Pesto. The 'UnicodeDecodeError' suggest that there's problem decoding response content using 'uft_32_le' encoding.

```
from pyhive import presto
import requests

# Connect to Presto with custom session
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Accept': 'text/plain'})
cursor = presto.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=10000,
    username='id:password',
    session=session
).cursor()

# Execute query
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10')

# Fetch results
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Here i have set 'Accept' header to 'text/plain'.

> Additionally, make sure your credentials are correct and presto server is running and reachable from your environment.